# Realm Objective-CをSwiftから使う際にマイグレーションのコードでコンパイルエラー

Tags: ios, swift, realm

現在、Realmの使い方を学んでいます。

そこで、http://qiita.com/jtemplej/items/10ed4bc0cc6519682e6e#notification のコードを下記のように書き写して、マイグレーションを勉強しています。

```
// Book.swift

class Book : RLMObject {
    dynamic var isbn = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var price = 0
    //サムネイルを追加したいから、imageURLを追加
    dynamic var imgURL = ""

    dynamic var publisher = Publisher()

    dynamic var owner: Publisher? {
        return linkingObjectsOfClass("Publisher", forProperty:"books").first as? Publisher
    }

    class func find(isbn:String) -> Book? {
        let result:Optional = Book.objectsWithPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "isbn = %@", isbn))
        if let books = result {
            return books.firstObject() as? Book
        }
        return nil
    }

    override class func primaryKey()->String{
        return "isbn"
    }
}
```

```
// AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import Realm

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion(1, forRealmAtPath:RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath() , withMigrationBlock: { (migration,oldSchemaVersion) in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(Book.className()) { (oldObject, newObject) in
                let book2 = newObject as! Book
                let isbn = oldObject["isbn"] as! String // <--ここで、'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'とエラーが出てしまう 
            }
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

上記のように、let isbn = oldObject["isbn"] as! Stringの部分で、'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'というエラーがでてしまう状態を解決できません。

どのようにすればよいのか教えてください。

Comment: 岸川さま
アンラップすることでエラーを解消することができました。
RealmSwiftについても、検討してみます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oldObject`および`newObject`はともにOptionalタイプですので、アンラップが必要になります。

（何が起こっているかは下記のように、一度キャストを無くしてみるとわかります。）

```
let isbn = oldObject["isbn"] // Cannot subscript a value of type 'RLMObject?' with an index of type 'String'
```

`oldObject`はオプショナル（`RLMObject?`）なので`oldObject["isbn"]`のように、そのままでは操作できません。
`oldObject?["isbn"]`か`oldObject!["isbn"]`などとしてアンラップする必要があります。

なので、該当の行を次のように修正すればビルドできます。

```
migration.enumerateObjects(Book.className()) { (oldObject, newObject) in
    let book2 = newObject as! Book
    let isbn = oldObject!["isbn"] // たとえば、強制アンラップする
}
```

**ちなみにSwiftを使う場合でiOS 8以降が対象なら、RealmSwiftというSwift専用のフレームワークのほうを使うと、APIがSwiftにより適した形になっているので、このようなOptionalの部分やキャストが必要な部分が無く、簡単に扱えるようになりますよ。**